# I can't connect to Cloud SQL even through direct IP

Tags: sql, postgresql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

So the system was working fine and suddenly, I lost conectivity to it through my systems. Logs don't show anything. Upon trying to connect using `gcloud connect`, I realize I can't even connect to the instance outside of my regular containers on GKE. I can't access it at all. I tried allowing all IPs and that doesn't help.

I'm at a loss here, any help?

Comment: Is there not any additional info about your system? Your CloudSQL config, network settings, ... Also, have you tried using the [CloudSQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy)? What kind of security do you have configured on your SQL instance? Is there any way to access the instance, or is it completely dead?

Comment: Did this happen just before you posted this? My external logs show connectivity issues starting just around the same time, going on for about 2 hrs. I'm Google Cloud SQL Postgres in Amsterdam. https://imgur.com/a/vN3Wlz1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this was a general issue: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-sql/18001